# Google Cloud Kubernetes ingress cost

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, google-cloud-load-balancer, kubernetes-gateway-api

I was wondering if the ingress controller of GKE comes either any additional costs, like a Google Cloud LoadBalancer, and if so is it possible to expose services with an ingress controller without the Google Cloud LoadBalancer. The same question is for GKE Gateway API.

I have tried to look at several pieces of documentation online and it is very contradicting.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no additional** cost running the **Ingress controller** with **GCP** however you have to pay for the **HTTP LoadBalancer** that **Ingress controller** create.

It will be the same for all **ingress** **controllers** you use **GCP**, **Nginx**, **Apache**.

While **Gateway** also it's the same, it's **controller** only provides more flexibility however with **Gateway** if you are leveraging **Managed SSL Certificates**, etc then you might have to pay for those **services**.

Incase if you would like to read more about **Ingress vs Gateway** checkout my article : https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-ingress-vs-gateway-api-647ee233693d

Comment: So both the ingress controller and the gateway use a load balancer to expose the applications to the internet.

Comment: yes and the controller manages rules and routes you defined.

Comment: And they require one forwarding rule, right? And there is no free tier for this?

Comment: sorry didn't get your question if you could share little more

Comment: The ingress controller or gateway both use a load balancer. And they both use one forwarding rule, do they use more/less. And is there a free tier so it is less expensive for having an ingress or gateway for my kubernetes cluster?

Comment: sorry i totally missed traveling, i think it would be minimum as if adding single routing rule in LB. i think there is no free tier single to five rules first cost in LB what i remember you can use calculator to get idea.